# Copying Xml File From Res/Xml Folder to Device Storage

Tags: android, xml, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to copy an xml file from the res/xml folder to the device storage but I'm really struggling on how to do this.

I know that the starting point is to get an `InputStream` to read the xml file. This is achieved by using this:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.xmlfile);
```

Eventually the output stream will be:

```
file = new File("xmlfile.xml");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

But I'm really struggling on how to read and copy all the information from the initial xml file correctly and accurately.

So far, I've tried using various `InputStream` and `OutputStream` to read and write (`DataInputStream`, `DataOutputStream`, `OutputStreamWriter`, etc.) but I still didn't managed to get it correctly. There are some unknown characters (encoding issue?) in the produced xml file. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `res/xml` you can't you have to put all files in your `assets` folder then use below code

```
Resources r = getResources();
AssetManager assetManager = r.getAssets();

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "dummy.xml");
InputStream is = = assetManager.open("fileinAssestFolder.xml");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f, true);

final int buffer_size = 1024 * 1024;
try
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer_size];
    for (;;)
    {
        int count = is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
        if (count == -1)
            break;
        os.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }
    is.close();
    os.close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it works, partly... can you explain to me why such buffer_size? and can you elaborate on the for loop. I've tried using your method and few others, but it seems like the newly created xml is either shorter, or much longer.. im still not sure why i cant get the exact xml as original.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the raw folder instead. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html.

Comment: yes, raw and assets folder (as suggested earlier by ingsaurabh) both works fine. but im still having another issue (as i commented in ingsaurabh's post) that maybe you could help too?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code:

```
   try {
        InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.XZY);
        OutputStream output = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("xyz.mp3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

And when you need file use this code:

```
File k =getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath("xyz.mp3");
```