# How to read xml file as text in Android

Tags: android, xml

First, I have an xml file in res/xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <rootelement1>
 <subelement>
 Hello XML Sub-Element 1
 </subelement>
 <subelement>
  Hello XML Sub-Element 2
  <subsubelement>Sub Sub Element</subsubelement>
  </subelement>
 </rootelement1>
```

I need to read all content of this file into string value (like read text file to the end and put to string)
I use XmlResourceParser but it does not help.

```
       StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
       Resources res = context.getResources();
       XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.myxmlfile);


       xpp.next();
       int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
       while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
       { 
           //add all text line by line, especially "<,>", attribute...
       }
```

How can I solve that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried just doing `res.getString(R.xml.myxmlfile);` ?

Comment: It does not help,just return the path of xml file: "res/xml/myxmlfile"

Comment: Interesting.  So if it gives you that path are you able to open it directly, like by using a standard `FileInputStream`?  Or even better, `res.openRawResource(R.xml.myxmlfile)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using XMLResourceParser when you have to read it as a text file? Why not simply use a BufferedReader with StringBuilder? However, to read a file from xml resources folder, try moving it to the raw, or (if by any means possible) to the assets folder first.

*Edit:*
To copy the respective file, you may use this link: [Copying XML from XML Resource to Device Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388373/copying-xml-file-from-res-xml-folder-to-device-storage)